# Do t.test on a matrix with R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a question related to but different from this one: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19121923/. I would like to do a t.test on a matrix of data, except that my matrix looks a bit different. I think I should use t.test with the "formula" and "data" attributes, but I'm not sure how I can reference my data correctly for this to work.

My data is a frequency matrix of word frequencies in a number of different literary texts and I'm interested in finding out which words have significantly different means in two groups of texts. Each column corresponds to one text; each row corresponds to one word; the values are the relative frequency of each word in each text. Here is what my data looks like (simplified crop of my much larger matrix).

```
     Moliere1     Moliere2     Regnard1     Regnard2
de   3.7942024586 3.8420867113 3.6368762334 3.3582683431
vous 3.0050083472 2.091411115  3.3126585847 2.705713831
et   2.3068750949 3.0666196687 2.8615731604 3.1036129238
je   2.2765214752 2.0679121137 1.8466309557 2.4033105205
```

Basically, I would like to find out which words have significantly different mean frequencies in each of the two authors' texts combined, something which is a hint at the stylistic difference between the two authors. I could split the matrix in two and/or rotate it if that is of any help. I know how to work this out in OpenOffice Calc, but it would be neat to do it with R. (I use an R package called "stylo" to create the frequency matrix in the first place.)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You are much more likely to receive an answer if you also provide attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. The link you refer to seems to be removed. Cheers.

Comment: You'll need the variances and sample sizes too for each word frequency and author.

Comment: Since your data are frequencies (scaled counts), would it make more sense to do some kind of analysis that relates to count data?

Comment: Can you elaborate on: "I would like to find out which words have significantly different mean frequencies in each of the two authors' texts combined" like you just want to compare Moliere to Regnard?